# Javascript onblur .focus loop madness

Tags: javascript, onblur

I have the following javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    function CheckInputValue(ThisField){
        var InputValue = ThisField.value;
        if(InputValue == ""){
            alert('You must enter a value in this field');
            setTimeout(function() {ThisField.focus();},0);
        }
    }
</script>
```

and the following HTML:

```
<label class="label1" for="inputb">inputb</label><input class="input1" id="inputb" onblur="CheckInputValue(this)">
<label class="label1" for="inputc">inputc</label><input class="input1" id="inputc" onblur="CheckInputValue(this)">
<label class="label1" for="inputd">inputd</label><input class="input1" id="inputd" onblur="CheckInputValue(this)">
```

The intended result is that when a field loses focus, the value is checked, and the user will be prompted if the field was left blank, and the focus will be set to that blank field.

However, When a user tabs from one input field to another without entering a value, the CheckInputValue script runs as expected, the alert message displays, but because focus is being changed by the user initiated tab, and then changed back by the script, a loop happens. How do I make this work, or am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: You can try to use `onchange` instead of `onblur`, it is triggered only when user really make changes to a value. However, I'd recommended you to validate your form just before submit. If there is an incorrect value, then inform user, and refuse to submit, before everything is OK.

Comment: I STRONGLY recommend that you don't do "required" field validation until you are ready to submit the form.  Otherwise, you are forcing your user to enter data in a specific order, which isn't a good user experience.  Unless there are other fields that are based on a value of earlier fields, just let your user fill in fields in the order that they want to and check that they've filled in all of the required ones at once.

Comment: Look into `addEventListener` instead of using `onblur` in the element in addition to fixing this bug. https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/DOM/elemento.addEventListener  
Also, you forgot to close the quotes for the label classes.

Comment: I was originally going to validate on form submission, but because there are many input fields which may appear on the form, based on user input, I thought that validating each field individually might be more efficient. It appears that validation on form submission may be the answer after all.

Comment: Accidentally posted the spanish version of the mdn docs. Use this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener instead

Comment: Looking into addEventListener and it may be a possible solution. Because of the dynamic nature of the form, the ability to validate each field individually would be a wonderful option, and addEventListener might work.